# How can I trace what installed a particular local library?

Tags: apt, dpkg

If I have a library located at `/usr/local/lib/foo.so` is there any way to trace what created/installed it? Ideally I'm looking for a way to remove all libs associated with opencascade, but I never manually installed anything, so hoping to find some uninstall or remove command from `apt`, `dpkg`, or `make` that would clean it all up.

This isn't necessarily restricted to `apt` and `dpkg`, but I figured those might be the most likely culprits for something automated that installed/created this library. I already checked the `/var/log/dpkg.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log` and didn't find anything with a modification date around the time `foo.so` was created.

I've also tried removing everything related to opencascade I could find here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/opencascade

via apt:

`sudo apt remove libocct*`

As the creation date of the file is older than any of the syslog archives, I'm resorting to trying to find files created around the same time with `find / -type f -newermt "2022-08-10 17:00" ! -newermt "2022-08-10 18:00"`.

Comment: I don't think *any* package from Ubuntu's standard repositories installs files to `/usr/local` (you can verify this using `apt-file` for example `apt-file search -x ^/usr/local/`)

Answer (score 2):

It only works the other way: you can tell what packages require a library. If the package is gone and not the library the system will not be able to tell you where it was installed from. Unless you depend on the cache (apt saves a copy of a package in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` but that can be removed manually).

You can list all current dependencies using `deporphan` though.

```
deborphan -d
```

It also has tools to remove orphaned packages (like libraries). The more used tool to remove those though is

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

to clean up from apt.

Install

```
sudo apt deborphan
```

> This isn't necessarily restricted to apt and dpkg,

`synaticp` and `aptitude` included in that list. But all other methods should stay away from the normal directories and use either /home/ or preferably /opt/.